# Does the event object on worker.onmessage ever contain anything interesting apart from data?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

When adding a callback to capture data transferred through web worker pipe, you do usually this:

```
worker.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    // Do something with data
      ...
});
```

I never touched any of the other properties and when I logged the event object into console, I didn't notice anything interesting. Since the creation of the `Event` object adds some overhead to message transfer I ask:

**Q:** Is there anything interesting about the `Event` object in webworker callbacks, or do we always just use `event.data`?

Comment: The MDN only mentions `data` as part of the `MessageEvent` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the creation of the Event object adds some overhead to message transfer

First, that's a moot point. The overhead is almost null here, just don't worry about it.

---

> Is there anything interesting about the Event object in webworker callbacks

The `MessageEvent` is not only used in "classic" workers messaging, but also in various places where a `MessageChannel` is being used. It will expose different information based on where it's been created. For instance when messaging between two WindowProxy objects, there will be a [`.source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/source) property that helps determining from where the message came from, along with a [`.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/origin) property, mostly useful for when the emitter is cross-origin.

But these aren't really interesting for classic Workers since there the emitter is always the context that created the Worker.

So the only two interesting properties you can look at when receiving a `MessageEvent` in a Worker are the `.data` indeed, and the `.ports`, which will contain the list of all the `MessagePort` objects that have been transferred in that message.

```js
// in main script
const { port1, port2 } = new MessageChannel();
worker.postMessage(data, [port1]);
```

```js
// in worker script
onmessage = ({ data, ports }) => {
  // Here you can access the transferred MessagePort
  const port = ports[0];
  ...
}
```

---

The fact that the same `MessageEvent` is being used for all the cases where a `MessageChannel` is used allows to extend that interface and have potentially new features added to all these case, for instance if one day we finally add access to all the transferred data, we'd just have to extend the interface so that it's accessible everywhere at once.

Answer (score 0):

Event objects in this case follow the [MessageEvents](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-webmessaging-20120501/#event-definitions) interface, which contains the following properties:

> The **data** attribute must return the value it was initialized to. When the object is created, this attribute must be initialized to null. It represents the message being sent.
>
> The **origin** attribute must return the value it was initialized to. When the object is created, this attribute must be initialized to the empty string. It represents, in server-sent events and cross-document messaging, the origin of the document that sent the message (typically the scheme, hostname, and port of the document, but not its path or fragment identifier).
>
> The **lastEventId** attribute must return the value it was initialized to. When the object is created, this attribute must be initialized to the empty string. It represents, in server-sent events, the last event ID string of the event source.
>
> The **source** attribute must return the value it was initialized to. When the object is created, this attribute must be initialized to null. It represents, in cross-document messaging, the WindowProxy of the browsing context of the Window object from which the message came.
>
> The **ports** attribute must return the value it was initialized to. When the object is created, this attribute must be initialized to null. It represents, in cross-document messaging and channel messaging the MessagePort array being sent, if any.

See the spec for more details.

Comment: Well I have read the specs and mdn. But my question was more practical. Specs, with their impertinent "*must return the value it was initialized to*", are far away from a practical interesting answer.